# Is there (or will be) a U1 referrals program?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Dropbox and CX.com have referral programs in which you earn storage by referring friends. Does Ubuntu One have such a program too?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no such a program, and I'm not aware of any that is being planned. You may feel free to suggest it on [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/), however.

Answer (score 2):

Keep an eye our to the twitter/facebook feed for possible announcements about this ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a referral program offered by Ubuntu One. If anybody wants to get a 500MB bonus on sign up, adding a referral link: https://one.ubuntu.com/referrals/referee/1070719/

Comment: Your "Referral" link wouldn't happen to link to YOUR referrals, would it?